# Restoring Samsung GT-P1000 to original firmware

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-tab, device-firmware

I spent the past several hours reading and reading. I tried to upgrade this Tablet to Jellybean, now the Tablet only reaches the Samsung glowing screen.

I tried several fixes to no avail, my first hurdle is I have no idea what Product code to place in to get the firmware from Sammobile as I dont know where this tablet originated from, possibly England. I also followed a tutorial on how to restore back to gingerbread 2.3.3 which gave me the same result; I think I have to go back to Froyo 2.2.

So I followed the tutorial from the answer on [Restoring original 2.2 firmware on Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000L](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22895/16575).

Again no luck, I think I need to restore everything. As I'm a noob maybe someone can point me the right direction? Also in the above tutorial I downloaded some PIT files, and I have no idea which one to use. Picking the correct firmware from Sammobile and PIT should reverse everything as I did load a modem file in the first place.

Comment: I can just hope you picked the correct "modem file". If you flashed an incompatible radio-ROM, there might be not much left you can do -- that's like flashing an incompatible BIOS-update to your PC.

Comment: Oh crap, can you not just re-flash another modem file?, Surely if the wrong modem file was used it wouldnt allow me to go into Download mode?, also Izzy would flashing the wrong modem file not just cut off connectivity but Tablet should work?, thanks, FYI im currently downloading carphone warehouse(CPW) United Kingdom Firmware as I found a "TalkMobile" sim in the tablet which from searching seems to be a mobile virtual network operator owned by (CPW).

Comment: Any suggestions what PID file to use?

Comment: Usually, if you flash the wrong "modem file", you're left with a "brick" (aka "paperweight"). If it was a "close relative", some stuff might still work -- you might even be lucky enough to get to download mode and flash the correct one over. Lesson: never touch the radio-rom if you're not absolutely sure what you're doing! It must absolutely match the hardware. Having chosen a "close relative" would perfectly explain your trouble. // As for the PID file (and everything else Sammy-specific), I'm not the right person to ask (I don't have a Sammy-Droid -- so I'm out at this point).

Comment: PS: To understand what that "modem file" is about (or rather the radio-firmware, which is what it updates), please read the [radio-firmware tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/radio-firmware/info). Takes you less than 2 minutes :)

Comment: Cool thanks Izzy, yup i read what each component is for, and this firmware contains, PDA, Modem etc.. all in one so i still cant figure out if it lets me flash again why my issue wont be resolved, modem for communications seem interchangeable according to what i've read when people loaded the wrong one but im just a noob so im being optimistic, thanks for your input i hope its not bricked.

Comment: Looks like I missed one thing, and "modem files" are again something Sammy-specific (never had any for my non-Sammy devices). You can read more in the SGS2 [Modems - Dummies Guide](http://androidforums.com/galaxy-s2-international-all-things-root/588852-modems-dummies-guide.html).

Comment: Izzy and for anyone else, after 8 hours this is the only think that worked for me!:D : http://suzhipackz.blogspot.ie/2012/07/how-to-re-stock-samsung-galaxy-tab.html

Comment: Glad to read you didn't bork your radio, but rather found a solution! Would you care compiling an answer, including that link and a short excerpt of its content (in case the linked page disappears one day)?